# How to refresh browser with Node.js when receive an externel event in the server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sockets

My situation is.. I created a webserver using Node.js. This webserver listen for events using a socket connection. When the socket connection received data I am changing the html content.. however how I can force a refresh in the browser ?

I just want to refresh the html page when I receive the socket event and I do not want to keep refreshing periodically.

I do not want use express.js because my system has some limitations.

I know there are a lot of solution to re-start the server when the file changes but it is not the case.. I would like to make the system very light and refreshing the pages only when the events are received.

Comment: So, to clarify: upon receiving the socket event in the browser you'd like it to refresh the page, not from cache?

Comment: Surely refreshing the page to get new data defeats the purpose of using the socket in the first place?

Comment: everything I want is not Node.js force the browser to refresh the page when some event is received.. I do not wait the user to press F5 or do something.. the refresh must be dynamic.. and of course not from cache because I am changing the page dynamically